# Libgdx | How to render 10,000 tiles?

Tags: java, android, optimization, libgdx

I am working on a topdown game for android, and I don't like using tiledmap. So I use my own tile class, each tile containing a sprite. The world is 100x100 (10,000) tiles. Now, for the game camera, I only render the tiles that are visible to the camera. But I have implimented a mini map, which views the whole screen, which means I will have to render 10,000 tiles. I tried using a spriteCache, which did indeed help, but I am still only getting about 25 fps :. I'm not sure any code is really necessary, considering I just render the game camera sprites via spritebatch, and mini map via spriteCache. I would greatly appreciate your help! I just don't understand how all of these 3d games can manage on android and this little 2d game can't. :|

Comment: Between 2D and 3D is no difference on libGDX side. We need to see some render code for your minnimap.

Comment: You should render a scaled down version of your world to the minimap.

Comment: Make sure you're using mip mapping or nearest filtering on your tile texture(s). Drawing a huge world scaled down like that will create a big performance hit if you don't. Search for mip mapping if you need an explanation for why.

Comment: Alternatively could draw your map to a FrameBuffer just one time when the map loads, and then draw the single FrameBuffer texture to the screen for the mini map. This would solve the minimizing issue and the mesh size issue as well.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I thought that is what a spriteCache does?

Comment: SpriteCache creates a static mesh, which means the mesh data doesn't have to be transferred to the GPU on every frame. But the GPU is still having to draw 40,000 vertices from your 10,000 sprites. If you render to a FrameBuffer, it becomes a single image which the GPU can draw with only 4 vertices. Also, you can size your FrameBuffer to the exact size it's going to be drawn on your screen, so you don't have to do texture filtering, which is really slow if you  are shrinking textures without mip mapping.

Comment: @tenfour04 Can you give me some more info on framebuffers? I have tried the following : Instantiating framebuffer object, then begin spritebatch, then begin framebuffer. I then loop through all tiles (This is in load method, so all this happens only once) and draw each tile sprite to the batch. What happens is when I try to render the framebuffer, nothing shows up. Did I render them correctly? Another possible problem is when I instantiate the frambuffer, it takes a width/height. Should that be my viewport height? Or just screensize?

Comment: @tenfour04 Also, when I draw each tile to the buffer, should I set the projection matrix to my viewport I will draw the framebuffer on? Thanks, sorry for my confusion.